# Passing array from js to Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend, backend

I have an array that is initialized when my user makes an input. I want that array to be passed to the nodeJS side of things rather than just stick around in the frontend. All the other variables that I am grabbing are named "net[object]" so I can grab them all in an array when necessary. The array I created only ever has one element being displayed in an input group at a time. If you need a better visual, go to "#nodes in hidden layer" for the neural net demo here: http://irisml.org/demos/

I am a complete noob when it comes to web development, so please be patient with me :)

```
//JS code creating array
numLayers.addEventListener('input', function(){
   nodesArray.length = 0
   num = numLayers.value;
   nodes.innerHTML = '';
   initialized = true;

   for(var i = 1; i < num - 1; i++){
      var node = document.createElement("option"); 
      var textnode = document.createTextNode("Nodes in Hidden Layer " + i);  
      node.appendChild(textnode);                              
      document.getElementById("nodes").appendChild(node);
      nodesArray.push(1) 
   } 
});


//Current NodeJS code
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

router.post('/', function(req, res){
   console.log(req.body.net)
});
```

Comment: You can use https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ to communicate with your nodejs endpoint.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, but how would I ensure that it is apart of the same post request as the other input variables?

Comment: By matching the urls of your ajax call to the router endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "fetch" to send a post request to the backend.

```js
        //frontend
   let nodesArray = [1,2,3];
   let body = JSON.stringify({net:nodesArray});
   fetch("/",
   {method:"post", 
    body:body,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }});
```

Your backend needs to listen on a port

```js
//backend
var express = require('express');
var app = new express();
app.use(express.json())
app.listen(3000, console.error); //listen on port http://localhost:3000

app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/static')); //OPTIONAL host static/index.html

app.post('/', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body.net, 'net');
    res.send("RESPONSE");
});
```